# Applet event programming

Tags: java, graphics, applet, awt, paint

i've made a smiley face in applet .. now what i want is that, when i move my mouse over the smiley it will change to sad face ....
i am not getting it(newbie in event programming) .... so please suggest me what to do next.....

Here is my code for Smiley->>>

## smiley.java

```
    import java.applet.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    public class smiley extends Applet implements MouseListener
     {


      public void init()
       {
         }
      public void paint(Graphics g)
        {


      g.setColor(Color.yellow);
      g.fillOval(40,40,120,150);
      g.setColor(Color.black);
      g.drawOval(61,75,20,20);
      g.setColor(Color.black);
      g.drawOval(115,75,20,20);
      g.fillOval(68,81,10,10);
      g.fillOval(121,81,10,10);
      g.setColor(Color.black);
      g.drawArc(75,95,50,50,180,180);


         }
      public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me)
       {
        }
       public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me)
        {

         }
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me)
        {

         }
       public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me)
       {

         }
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me)
       {

         } 

         }
```

Answer (score 1):

At some point, you need to register you listener with the applet.

See [Component.addMouseListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#addMouseListener%28java.awt.event.MouseListener%29).

Try in your `init` or `start` method adding `addMouseListener(this)`

Some pointers.

- You should always call `super.paint()`.  The paint methods do a lot of important work behind the scenes
- You should, where you can, avoid overriding the `paint` methods of the top level components.  They're not double buffered and will tend to "flash" on redraw.
- If you can, you should favor Swing components of AWT components

And because I know the question will come...

```
public class SadApplet extends JApplet {

    private boolean mouseOver = false;

    public void init() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new FacePane());
    }

    protected class FacePane extends JPanel implements MouseListener {

        public FacePane() {
            addMouseListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            g.setColor(Color.yellow);
            g.fillOval(40, 40, 120, 150);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawOval(61, 75, 20, 20);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawOval(115, 75, 20, 20);
            g.fillOval(68, 81, 10, 10);
            g.fillOval(121, 81, 10, 10);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            if (!mouseOver) {
                g.drawArc(75, 95, 50, 50, 180, 180);
            } else {
                g.drawArc(75, 95 + 50, 50, 50, 180, -180);
            }


        }

        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {
            mouseOver = true;
            repaint();
        }

        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {
            mouseOver = false;
            repaint();
        }

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
        }

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply  @Madprogrammer but  is there any way through which i can change the value of g.drawArc(75,95,50,50,180,180); to g.drawArc(75,95,50,50,300,300); 
when i move my cursor over it .... it will be so easy in that way ....

Comment: you should favor Swing components of AWT components.Why?

Comment: @ankit Extract the mouse location of the form mouse event using [MouseEvent.getPoint](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html#getPoint()). Use a if statement to determine iftgecursor is within the prescribed rectangle

Answer (score 0):

Put code that re-draws your smily into `mouseEntered()` and `mouseExited()`: `mouseEntered()` should draw "other" face, `mouseExited()` should draw the same face again.

Comment: will you plz show me by writting code here..